# Android - Firebase searching with filtering

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm developing an app that will help the user to search the books and download them which have been uploaded by other users as a form of the post.

---

In order to download the books first, the user should search them owing to attribute such as Title.

[image]

---

The posts which meet the requirement of the user should be displayed in the **firebase-UI** recyclerview.

---

This is my Firebase data structure:

[image]

---

I want the sample code that will create a **Query**  which returns Id of convenient Posts such as **ImgBRr2YFYfAu1WwENS1Ucj6jz13_1514813350760**.

---

Please help me to solve the problem, any suggestions and ideas will be welcomed

Comment: on which basis you want to search id from firebase ?

Comment: The value of **author   language title** should be the same the texts in the edit text fields

Comment: So you are taking input `author`, `language` and `title` from user and want this post id from firebase ?

Comment: Yes, please, maybe more helpfully you can help me to create a query that will return ID according to similarity range for example from 100% similar to 80% similar. But may be :D

Comment: But this is not possible. You can perform only one query at a time on firebase. So, perform searching either by use author, language or title.

Comment: Okay i have edited the question, could you help me to create autocomplete with Books title after Clicking the item of AutoComplete it will display all book with the Title of Written text.

Comment: Yup it can be performed easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do,

For search by language and then filter by title & author

```
public void search(String languangeSearchString, String title, String author){  
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").equalTo("language").startAt(languangeSearchString).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                 String id = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                if(dataSnapshot.child("title").exists() && dataSnapshot.child("author").exists()){
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class).equals(title) && dataSnapshot.child("author").getValue(String.class).equals(author)){
                        //Here are the results
                    }
                }           
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: How can i get the id of the post from your method? Please also add this to your answer

Answer (score 1):

To perform searching on `firebase-database`, we commonly use `orderBy()`. Like

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts").child("postId")
                        .orderBy("authorId")
```

But it can't possible to use multiple `orderBy()` like,

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts").child("postId")
                     .orderBy("authorId")
                     .orderBy("title")     // this will throw an error
                     .orderBy("language")
```

So you have to perform searching only on one `child-node`.
For more info check this [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: The problem is that i don't know the ID of the Post, because it is hashed string code....

Comment: As shown in image, you saved `postid` in your `db` so use it.

Comment: How will I get the Id of a searching post now? How would you get?